# Creating New layers in SHARPMAP

Tags: c#, maps, sharpmap

I'm working on sharpmaps, Say i have a map of US , how to add new layers over the maps ?

As i need to write the name of the state over the basic layer and color each state with different colours. 
Is it possible to achive this goal in Sharpmaps...?

Comment: I think that this link [here](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CustomTheme&referringTitle=Styling%20based%20on%20feature%20data) helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use "custom them" for  color each state and "label layer" for name of the state

You must first one delegate method define.The delegate takes a FeatureDataRow as parameter and you can handle the custom style

for example

```
private SharpMap.Styles.VectorStyle GetCountryStyle(SharpMap.Data.FeatureDataRow row)
{
    SharpMap.Styles.VectorStyle style = new SharpMap.Styles.VectorStyle();
    switch (row["NAME"].ToString().ToLower())
    {
        case "denmark": //If country name is Danmark, fill it with green
            style.Fill = Brushes.Green;
            return style;
        case "united states": //If country name is USA, fill it with Blue and add a red outline
            style.Fill = Brushes.Blue;
            style.Outline = Pens.Red;
            return style;
        case "china": //If country name is China, fill it with red
            style.Fill = Brushes.Red;
            return style;
        default:
            break;
    }
    //If country name starts with S make it yellow
    if (row["NAME"].ToString().StartsWith("S"))
    {
        style.Fill = Brushes.Yellow;
        return style;
    }
    // If geometry is a (multi)polygon and the area of the polygon is less than 30, make it cyan
    else if (row.Geometry is GeoAPI.Geometries.IPolygonal && row.Geometry.Area < 30)
    {
        style.Fill = Brushes.Cyan;
        return style;
    }
    else //None of the above -> Use the default style
        return null;
}
```

and then set the Theme property of your layer to this method

```
SharpMap.Rendering.Thematics.CustomTheme myTheme = new SharpMap.Rendering.Thematics.CustomTheme(GetCountryStyle);
myVectorLayer.Theme = myTheme ;
```

and for label Layer you must new layer as LabelLayer define
for example

```
//Name of table in database
string tablename = "Roads"; 
//Name of object ID column - MUST be integer!
string idColumn = "gid";

//Create layer
SharpMap.Layers.VectorLayer layRoads= new SharpMap.Layers.VectorLayer("Roads");
layRoads.DataSource = datasource;
//Set up a road label layer
SharpMap.Layers.LabelLayer layRoadLabel = new SharpMap.Layers.LabelLayer("Road labels");
//Set the datasource to that of layRoads.
layRoadLabel.DataSource = layRoads.DataSource;
layRoadLabel.Enabled = true;
//Specifiy field that contains the label string.
layRoadLabel.LabelColumn = "RoadOfName";

//Add layer to map
myMap.Layers.Add(layRoads);
//Add label layer to map
myMap.Layers.Add(layRoadLabel);
```

tells all  [here](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CustomTheme&referringTitle=Styling%20based%20on%20feature%20data)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is possible in sharpmaps.

However, in c# it can be achieved by mapping the coordinates of the state boundaries.